# Program is inverting entered function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The purpose of my code is to print a text-based function graph. However, when printing the graph, it prints the inverse of the function I provide it with, for example my input x+2 and it produces the graph of f(x)=-x+2, and when entering x**2+1, it prints the graph of f(x)=sqrt(x-1). This is the code:

```
import math
function = input ("Enter a function f(x):\n")
for x in range(-10,11):
    for y in range(-10,11):
        if round (eval (function))==y:
            print ("o", end="")
            y=y+1
        elif x==0 and y==0:
            print ("+", end="")
            y=y+1
        elif x==0:
            print ("-", end="")
            y=y+1
        elif y==0:
            print ("|", end="")
            y=y+1
        else:
            print (" ", end="")
    print ("")
```

I can't figure out where I went wrong and why the program is inverting the function I enter. How do I fix this?

Comment: When you step through this in a debugger, at what specific point does the behavior not match what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to this, and therefore don't know how to use a debugger properly... It just seems to be taking whatever operation I'm doing to the x at input and inverting it, so x becomes -x, x squared becomes the squareroot of x...

Answer (score 6):

Because you're iterating over `y` starting from the **bottom** (largest negative number), but when you `print` the lines you inevitably start from the **top**. You also have the loops the wrong way around - you need to do each **line** in turn (iterate `y`) and do each **column** in turn (iterate `x`) within that. Switch to:

```
for y in range(10, -11, -1):  # decending rows
    for x in range(-10, 11):  # columns left to right
        if round(eval(function)) == y:
            print ("o", end="")
        elif x==0 and y==0:
            print ("+", end="")
        elif y==0:
            print ("-", end="")
        elif x==0:
            print ("|", end="")
        else:
            print (" ", end="")
    print ("")
```

Note that I've switched `x` and `y` within the loops, and removed the redundant increment to `y`. For `function == "x+2"` this gives me:

```
          |       o  
          |      o   
          |     o    
          |    o     
          |   o      
          |  o       
          | o        
          |o         
          o          
         o|          
--------o-+----------
       o  |          
      o   |          
     o    |          
    o     |          
   o      |          
  o       |          
 o        |          
o         |          
          |          
          |
```

and for `function == "x**2"`:

```
          |          
       o  |  o       
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
        o | o        
          |          
          |          
         o|o         
----------o----------
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |          
          |
```

Comment: Does it work for x**2?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso it does now!

Comment: Now it is perfect, then!